# Lightbox is opening in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am trying to use lightbox on one of my web pages, but after loading the jquery library and lightbox.js as well as lighbox.css, when an image associated with lightbox is clicked, it is opened in a new window.  I have found that if I disable my standard jquery file, lightbox works fine.  I'm pretty new to javascript and Jquery, can anyone see why this might be interfering with lightbox?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menuButton").click(function(){
        $('#sideContent').toggleClass('hide');
        $('nav').toggleClass('hide');
        $('#key').toggleClass('big');
        $('#pageSize').toggleClass('big');
        $('#returnContainer').toggleClass('hide');
        $('#returnText').toggleClass('hide');
   });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#collapseGallery').click(function () {
        $('#galleryImg').toggleClass('hide');
    })
})


$(document).ready(function () {
    var $window = $(window),
        $key = $('#key'),
        topOffset = $key.offset().top;
        $window.scroll(function () {
            $key.toggleClass('fixed', $window.scrollTop() > topOffset);
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#returnContainer').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
    })
})
```

HTML (of the page my gallery is on):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
      <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" /> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.css" /> 
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
       <!-- <script src="js/js.js"></script>-->

        <title>School</title>
    </head>

    <body>
                <?php include ("aside.php"); ?>
                <div id="pageSize">
                <header class="pageHeader">
                    Schoolwork
                </header>
                    <div class="contentHeader">
                        <h1>Work From CCC</h1>
                    </div>
                <div class="content">

                <div class="hLine"></div>
                <p>Some text.</p>
                <br>

                <div>
                    <h1 id="collapseGallery">Contemporary Issues in Painting</h1>
                    <div id="galleryImg" class="hide">
                            <?php include 'images.php'; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    </body>

<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
</html>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Okay, I've got them both to function properly, it seems that I have to load my own js file after lightbox, but for some reason, the return to top of page function still refuses to work.

Comment: If that's part of the same problem, edit your question and add it in. If it's a unrelated problem, ask a new question. Comments like that often get overlooked.